# Create Custom CSS Shape

Tags: css, shapes

Any ideas I can create this shape with CSS only? No SVG path~

Thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZFVW.png)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use SVG?

Comment: Because I want it also show on old browsers, like IE10~

Comment: FWIW IE10 supports SVG: https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg . IE10 usage is now below 0.2% now - it's not worth targeting anyway even if it didn't support SVG.

Comment: That doesn't mean nobody use, I need to target to these people too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something like this. The idea is you could potentially create your own unique clip path here [clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

```
clip-path: polygon(0 56%, 8% 51%, 14% 48%, 24% 44%, 31% 39%, 38% 34%, 45% 30%, 
51% 28%, 56% 29%, 62% 33%, 68% 38%, 74% 42%, 81% 47%, 86% 51%, 94% 51%, 100% 
55%);
```

Comment: another option would be to use `<canvas>` https://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas it is supported on IE

this is an example of what you can draw on the canvas https://codepen.io/jolx/pen/EVGyVP

Comment: Canvas maybe a solution~

Answer (score 0):

Albeit not exactly what you are looking for, just an effort. You can probably tweak the CSS to give it a better looking shape.

```css
.main {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  height: 45px;
  width: 90px;
  border-top-left-radius: 90px;
  border-top-right-radius: 90px;
  position:absolute;
  top:3px;
  left:24px;
}

.quarter-left {
  width:20px; 
  height:20px; 
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0 0 90px 0;
  position:absolute;
  top:27px;
  left:9px;
  z-index:1;
}

.quarter-right {
  width:20px; 
  height:20px; 
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 90px;
  position:absolute;
  top:28px;
  left:110px;
  z-index:1;
}


.right{
     width:0; 
     height:0; 
     border-right:20px solid transparent;
     border-top:20px solid transparent;
     border-left:20px solid red;
     border-bottom:20px solid red;
     position:absolute;
     top:8px;
     left:90px;
}

.left{
     width:0; 
     height:0; 
     border-right:20px solid red;
     border-top:20px solid transparent;
     border-left:20px solid transparent;
     border-bottom:20px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="quarter-left"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="quarter-right"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```